# mySQL: Query performance with User Defined Functions

Tags: mysql, user-defined-functions, multilingual, query-performance

I'm trying to make a multi-language mySQL database. 
I was considering using user defined functions to determine which column in a table to read - where different columns will store the different translations - however I was concerned about query performance.

For example, if I wanted to return a list of Cities, and the name of country - with the latter returned in multiple languages. At what point would the below approach impact performance? - as I might do an equivalent on a table with 2-5,000 rows.

Country table structure:

> ```
>   SELECT
>     `CountryID`,
>     `Name_English`,
>     `Name_French`,
>     `Name_Spanish`
> FROM `Country`
> WHERE `CountryID` = fCountryID;
> ```

City Table Structure:

```
SELECT 
    `City`.`CityName` 'City' 
    ,getCountry(1, `City`.`CountryID`) 'Country'
FROM `City`;
```

Example Function Call:

> ```
>   SELECT 
>     `City`.`CityName` 'City' 
>     ,getCountry(1, `City`.`CountryID`) 'Country'
> FROM `City`;
> ```

Full Function:

> delimiter $$
>      CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION 
>       `getCountry`(`fLanguageID` INT, `fCountryID` SMALLINT) 
>       RETURNS varchar(100) CHARSET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci
>   BEGIN

```
DECLARE returnCountry VARCHAR(100);

IF (fLanguageID = 1) -- English
THEN

    SET returnCountry =  (

        SELECT `Name_English` FROM `Country`
        WHERE `CountryID` = fCountryID

    );

ELSEIF (fLanguageID = 2) -- French
THEN
    SET returnCountry =  (

        SELECT `Name_French` FROM `Country`
        WHERE `CountryID` = fCountryID

    );


ELSEIF (fLanguageID = 3) -- Spanish
THEN
    SET returnCountry =  (

        SELECT `Name_Spanish` FROM `Country`
        WHERE `CountryID` = fCountryID

    );

END IF;

RETURN returnCountry;


SELECT
    `CountryID`,
    `Name_English`,
    `Name_French`,
    `Name_Spanish`
FROM `Country`
WHERE `CountryID` = fCountryID;

SELECT 
    `City`.`CityName` 'City' 
    ,getCountry(1, `City`.`CountryID`) 'Country'
FROM `City`;
```

END$$

Comment: Why you don't use IF or SWITCH to select the right language field. So you can join both tables and you don't need the function.

Comment: It's because as things develop, more languages will be added. So I don't want to have to go through each stored proc, etc to look for (and miss changes).
I think it might work OK for small returns, but I was wondering when it would hit a limit - and I would have to more intelligent with IF/SWITCH/CAS, etc

Comment: If you create a translation table, with reference to countries, then you havent to choose a language-field. Additional you can hold a default name in your country table. So you can make a left join to translation, with country id and language id.

Comment: OK, that's a much better idea than what I've done - thanks.
So presumably;
SELECT IFNULL(cl.Name, c.Name)
FROM tblCountry c
LEFT JOIN tblCountry_translate cl ON cl.CountryID = c.CountryID AND cl.LanguageID = <LangaugeParameter>

?